# Can i fire or execute a javascript function on the change of class on object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to execute a function when the element 's class updated (any new class add or remove).

how i can do this in jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to set up a custom event.

```
//function to receive event
$('#foo').bind('class_change', function() {
      alert("Class changed");
    });

//use trigger() to fire custom event
$('#foo').addClass("newClass").trigger('class_change');

$('#foo').removeClass("newClass").trigger('class_change');
```